# saving images in an array after getting them form the web using kingfisher

Tags: swift, image, kingfisher

I am using kingfisher library to get images from the web and display them in an image view . each 5 seconds I'm getting a new Image and display it. I want to get the images, save them in an array and then display them, in order no to get the images every time from the web. just get them one time and store them in an array, and read them from the array.
my code now :

```
    var imagesURL = Array<String>() // contains the images urls
    var counter = 0
.
.

func fireTimer()  {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(setImagesInImageView), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func setImagesInImageView()  {
              let url = URL(string: self.imagesURL[counter] )
             self.imageDisplayer.kf.setImage(with: url)
            counter = counter + 1
        }
```

any help?

Comment: Kingfisher already has a built-in cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kingfisher saves all loaded images to local cache. You don't need to store images in array. Just store an URLs of images in array and Kingfisher will load cached images automatically.